# Adapt WCF automatically to current resources?

Tags: performance, wcf, settings, throttling

Is it possible to adapt a WCF service to the current resources, for example change the concurrent calls to a lower nr if the ram is low?

BestRegards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's already the case since .net 4 (see blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx)).
However, only the number of processor is important.

- **MaxConcurrentSessions**: default is 100 * ProcessorCount
- **MaxConcurrentCalls**: default is 16 * ProcessorCount
- **MaxConcurrentInstances**: default is the total of the above two, which follows the same pattern as before.

HTTP is a stateless protocol and it's recommanded to avoid using session on server side, for scalability. A typical front end server, consumme CPU and not memory (ScaleOut Vs ScaleUp).

However, WCF limits, aka WCF throttling is just a behavior. You add/edit this behavior at startup using a ServiceHost a custom ServiceHostFactory.

```
ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
throttle.MaxConcurrentCalls = /*what you want*/;
throttle.MaxConcurrentSessions = /*what you want*/;
throttle.MaxConcurrentInstances = /*what you want*/; 

ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService));    
// if host has behaviors, remove them.
if (host.Description.Behaviors.Count != 0)
{
   host.Description.Behaviors.Clear();
}
// add dynamically created throttle behavior
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);

//open host
host.Open();
```

You can achieve the same using a custom [ServiceHostFactory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx).

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyWebApplication.TestService"
                Factory="MyWebApplication.TestServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, My main problem is however not speed but outOfMemmory exceptions and if we would set MaxConccurentCalls to a lower nr maby the problem would go away. But then setting MaxConcurrentCalls and MaxConccurentSessions to 10 it seems like the service freezes at the 10 user.

Comment: Well it's true, you can't really change these settings without changing something in your Service (SessionManagement or Instancing,  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx. Also try to check WCF performance counters values such as Percent of Max Concurrent Calls (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427644.aspx)